# Which to use Coroutine or Update to slow down animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do

1. gradually stop car animation as it collildes with another car
2. gradually speed up car animation as it exit the collider

And I have two ways to acheive this thing(means to run my logic in).

1. Update
2. Co-routine

for coroutine I used this

```
IEnumerator IncreaseSpeedGradually1(AnimationControlSpeed lastGOHitScript)
{
    //stop if decrease speed in progress
    StopCoroutine("DecreaseSpeedGradually");
    float decrementValue = ((lastHitVehicleSpeed / 2) * 2);
    while (lastGOHitScript.Speed <= lastHitVehicleSpeed)
    {
        lastGOHitScript.Speed += decrementValue * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }
    //setting speed to the last speed
    lastGOHitScript.Speed = lastGOHitScript.iniSpeeed;
}
```

While for update I just make this criteria:

```
if (carAnimState == carAnimationState.starting)
{
    carAnimState = carAnimationState.running;
}

if (carAnimState == carAnimationState.stoping)
{
    carAnimState = carAnimationState.running;
}
```

These two ways I know but i want to ask that which is right way to do this job? to slow down animation speed and hence get my objective? I guess corroutine later can be problematic in my game and what are the performance concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Not perfectly clear what your goal exactly is. What you describe is clear, but the two code snippets you posted do completely different things. BUT, basically, for something this small I would use Update() as it's easier to debug if something blows up and there's nothing -theoretically- in your code that wishes "threading" / "side tasking" (which coroutines are for, basically: do something -most probably a side task- async).

As a side note, the code in your Update() can be optimized a little so it will look something like this:

```
if (carAnimState == carAnimationState.starting) {
    carAnimState = carAnimationState.running;
} else if (carAnimState == carAnimationState.stoping) {
    carAnimState = carAnimationState.running;
} //this way the 2nd "if" won't be unnecessarily evaluated when animstate was .starting
```

I'd also add a method instead and call that from Update(). The pre-compiler will inline it most probably (cannot be forced in Unity) and your code is more readable.

Comment: coroutine looks more efficient as compare to update because update require bool or state which will check continously and its can make performance overhead

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Processing capacity is processing capacity. It doesn't matter if Update() works or a Coroutine from this respect, especially if the job has to be done in one go. Coroutine's power is in "asynchronouty", i.e. whatever the operation they do, can be "split up" between frames ("yield" command). BTW you don't need to return anything (can do just "yield;") if you don't use the value, as well as you don't have to add "IEnumerator" in this case.